# Length Function in R

Tags: r, function

How do I use the Length function in R to compare how many more of Item A than Item B? (see help(length))

I want this to be the output 10 (if there 20 items of A and 10 items of B).

Comment: `abs(length(A) - length(B))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your A and B are both vectors.
If you just want to know how much is A>B:

```
> A=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> B=c(1,2,3)
> length(A)-length(B)
[1] 2
```

If you want to know the difference of the lengths of the two vectors:

```
> A=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> B=c(1,2,3)
> abs(length(A)-length(B))
[1] 2
```

Comment: This is not different from the @rawr's solution in the comments.  If you are using the same solution, please do acknowledge it in the post

Comment: The actual question requires determining how many more juniors in class A versus in class B. I am tryingg to use both the length and the which function any thoughts?